# Use JSTL or jQuery forEach loop's over set from model

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have jsp page, which recive in model a set like this: ['a', 'c']. Set can be bigger.

We have some checkboxes for example:

```
<input name="a" type="checkbox">
<input name="b" type="checkbox">
<input name="c" type="checkbox">
...
```

If in the set the values correspondings to the `<input>` attribute **name** - we need put attribute **"checked"** to this `<input>`.

I have a solution using jQuery:

```
var arr = '${resource}'.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace(' ', '').split(','); // make array from string

for (var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){
$('input[name='+arr[i]+']').prop('checked',true);
}
```

But (if it will be more simpler solution) how it can be done with JSTL tags?

Comment: By the way, your array declaration is overcomplicated. Just do `var arr = ${resource};`. JSP is just a HTML/JS code generator which doesn't run "in sync" with JS at all.

Comment: In variant: var arr = ${resource}; alert(arr[0]) - I will recive "a is not defined". How can I use this arr in JS like an array?

Comment: That will happen if it's null or empty.